# How to put field value in footer Kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I want to get a value from a field in my grid, and put it in the footer of the grid. Is there a smart way to do it like

```
       columns: [
            {field: "product", title: "Product"},
            {field: "price", title: "Price"},
            {field: "priceDoubledInFooter", title:"priceDoubledInFooter",footerTemplate:#=price*price#},

        ]
```

Comment: have you looked at this example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

Comment: yes, i did, but i dont need group templates, and aggregates, i need just to copy a value from a field to a footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a simple dojo for you: http://dojo.telerik.com/UWOvi/2

This shows the contact names within the demo grid in a bootstrap popover when clicked.

Without knowing your specific needs I have included all the values from one column into the popover.

This is achieved by creating a function called `getMeValues()` that is assigned to the footerTemplate.

This function then does the following:

```
  function getMeValues(data)
  {
    var gridDS = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(); 

    var result = ''; 

    gridDS.forEach(function(row, index){
      result += index + '::' + row.ContactName + '<br/>';
    }); 

return '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-title="I am some data" data-content="' +   result + '"/>' + ' Click Me</button>';
```

}

I gain access to the `data` within the dataSource for the grid and then iterate over the ContactName field and add that to a var. I finally then create a button which is placed in the footer which activates a popover to display the contents.

Then to get the newly created button to function I bind the popover event within the `dataBound` event of the grid so that it knows to activate the button for me.

Obviously change this example for your specific needs but if you have any further questions I'll be happy to help.

Comment: hey, now i need only one row, the foreach loop is not needed. How can i acces to the row value without the function(row,index)?

Comment: how do you know which row you want to access? if you know the row you can just hit the index of the array that is returned from the grid's data collection. eg. `gridDS[10]` would access row 11 of the data collection

Comment: i tried haha, but now i need to get a string value from that. Im getting [object Object]

Comment: if you are getting the item you then you need to reference the property you are after from that item eg `gridDS[10].SomeProperty`

Comment: var valueRandom = gridDS[0].base;
 alert(valueRandom); and im getting TypeError: gridDS[0] is undefined hmm, base is SomeProperty

Comment: I used that code as an example. You need to return the property of the item you are accessing, if you can provide a sample (dojo/jsfiddle) I can advise better

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KndsD1KP here is the code for the grid and the function. Hope it can get you some clarity to the situation. Thanks!

Comment: I have prepared this dojo for you. http://dojo.telerik.com/eWEyI/3 I have set the template to show the first item in the list if you change the index you will see the footer change accordingly